# How can I run a function after another is done in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js to draw several bars. After the drawing is done, I want to change the color of selected bars, but it always fails. It seems `drawBars()` and `updateColor()` are called at the same time.

```
function redraw(data){
    drawBars(data);
    updateColor();
}
```

How can I ensure `drawBars()` is done before the `updateColor()` is called?

At first, I added the update function code at the end of drawBar, it didn't work. Later, I moved it to end of the redraw function, it didn't work either.
This is specific code:

```
function drawBar(drawData){
        var w = 1060,h = 600;
        d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
        var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);   

        uni.forEach(function(element,index,array){
        $('.uni').css("top",function(index){
                return  (index + 1) * 18 + 28;
            });
        });
        $(".rankingheader").css("display","block");
        $("#switch input").prop("checked", false);
        starData = drawData; 
        revCountData = drawData;
        sentData = drawData;
        bizCountData = drawData;


        drawAxis(drawData);
        drawStar(starData);
        drawRev(revCountData);
        drawSent(sentData);
        drawBiz(bizCountData);
        drawLineA(starData);
        drawLineB(starData,revCountData);
        drawLineC(revCountData,sentData);
        drawLineD(sentData,bizCountData);

                    // cart is a list which stored the id selected by user
        if(cart.length > 0){
                cart.forEach(function(element,index,array){
                    d3.select("#starHoverLine" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#starHintText" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#revHoverLine" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#revHintText" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#sentHoverLine" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#sentHintText" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#bizHoverLine" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#bizHintText" + element).attr("visibility","visible");
                    d3.select("#lineA" + element).style("stroke","red");
                    d3.select("#lineB" + element).style("stroke","red");
                    d3.select("#lineC" + element).style("stroke","red");
                    d3.select("#lineD" + element).style("stroke","red");
                    d3.select("#starBar" + element).attr("fill","red");
                    d3.select("#revBar" + element).attr("fill","red");
                    d3.select("#sentBar" + element).attr("fill","red");
                    d3.select("#bizBar" + element).attr("fill","red");
                });
        }

    }
```

Comment: No, they are called one after another.

Comment: Is `drawBars` making an ajax request? If it is not and it's just executing code that runs inline then it should be done.

Comment: You'll have to show the code for `drawBars`. Either it does something asynchronous, in which case usually asynchronous ops offer a callback or promise on completion; or you just want to yield briefly back to the browser to let it render the bars, in which case you want `setTimeout`. Impossible to say which right now.

Comment: Put updateColor() inside drawBars() at the last line if you want to guarantee that drawBars executes before updateColor, Knowing that the execution of the current code is sequential

Comment: plz edit your question with details, some code its needed to answer

Comment: Sometimes the browser optimizes calls which alter the DOM tree and redraws the page after JS stops modifying the DOM tree, so you won't see the intermediate state. Is this the case?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/mbostock/queue

Answer (score 1):

Your two functions are not called simultaneously; they're called one after another. If it appears that they're being called simultaneously, one of two things is happening:

1. `drawBars` is *starting* something that finishes asynchronously (like an ajax request or an animation), or
2. `drawBars` is making changes that aren't shown by the browser immediately and you want to yield back to the browser briefly to allow it to show (render) those changes before calling `updateColor`.

If it's #1, then you'll need to look at the documentation for the asynchronous operation that `drawBars` is starting to find out how to know when it finishes. Usually this is a callback or a promise. Depending on which it is, you'll either need to pass `updateColors` into `drawBars` as an argument (so you can then call it from the asynchronous callback), or have `drawBars` return the promise and use the promise's `then` method to add `updateColors` to the queue of functions to call when the promise is fulfilled.

If it's #2, that's much simpler:

```
setTimeout(updateColors, 100); // Wait 100ms (1/10th second) and call `updateColors`
```